# Nullify Data validation in some forms MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post, data-annotations, actionresult

I have used `Data Annonation` in my project to validate my modals. e.g I have a class with following `Data Annonation` properties

```
 public class tbl_store
 {
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is required")]
    public string Name{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "Please enter a valid e-mail adress")]
    public string Email{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Phone Number is required")]
    [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid Phone number")]
    public string Contact{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is required")]
    public string Address{ get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Detail is required")]
    public string Detail{ get; set; }
}
```

Now i have a form that use the above class as `Model` and have input textboxes for `Name` , `Email` and `Contact` fields.

When i submit this form, i am using following `ActionResult` method

```
  [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult createStore(tbl_store modal)
    {
        try
        {
            using (joyryde_storeEntities context = new joyryde_storeEntities())
            {

                    tbl_store objStore = new tbl_store()
                    {
                        Name = modal.Name,
                        Email = modal.Email,
                        Contact = modal.Contact                          
                    };
                    context.tbl_store.Add(objStore);
                }                   
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
        {

        }
       // Some more code
    }
```

Here at `Context.SaveChanges()` exception throws with message `System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.`

When i debug the expcetion,  it throws me exception due to `Address` and `Detail` fields are required fields and are posted with `null` values.

I don't wanna add this fields in this form.

How can i nullify `Data Annonation` for these two fields or some things else to post this form data successfully.

Comment: Then, as always, use view models containing only the properties you want in the view(s) and map to and from your data model.

Comment: I have another form, that uses the same data modal class to submit `Address` and `Details` later for the same store.

Comment: Which is why you use view models!

Answer (score 1):

You must use view model. View models are some model for creating models that has diffrence property and attributes from the main model. create viewmodel directory in model directory and add your new model that `address` and `details` are not required.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not your use/not use of view models. The problem is your database. I assume you are using EF Code First. You have to remove the Required Attributes from your entity to be able to save it to the database without the error you are facing now. If you are not using EF Code First, in addition to removing the attributes, you have to change your database to allow NULL-Values in the 2 columns.

However if you want another view where these 2 fields are required, you have to use 2 view models which will do individual check for each view.
One for Name, Email and Contact and another one for Address and Detail.